# How do I limit the number of spaces between the headings of contents and list of figures/tables and the first item?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I am trying to write a document in latex, and I need there to be no more than one blank line between the word "contents" and the first item in the table of contents.

The same requirement is for the list of figures and list of tables; there can be no more than one blank line between the phrase "list of ..." and the first item.

The phrases "contents","list of..." have to be all caps, normals size, and centered (all of which has been done in the code below), but I cannot figure out how to remove the spaces between the phrases and the first item.

Below is a condensed version of my code:

```
\documentclass[14.5pt]{report}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\bullet$}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize CONTENTS \hfill}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\normalsize \hspace{2.4in} LIST OF FIGURES}

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\normalsize  \hspace{2.4in}  LIST OF TABLES}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{chngpage}

\usepackage[labelsep=period,figurename = FIG.]{caption}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\marginsize{1.0in}{1.0in}{1.0in}{1.0in}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancyhf{}

\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage

BODY HERE
\chapter{first}
\begin{table}
  \caption{first table}
  \label{tab:first}

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
       item & item \\
       item & item \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\section{first section}
\begin{figure}
                      \begin{center}
                        %\includegraphics[width=5in]{Pictures/needsimprovement}
                        \vspace{5in}
                        \caption{first figure}
                        \label{fig:first}
                      \end{center}
                    \end{figure}        
\chapter{second}
\begin{table}
  \caption{second table}
  \label{tab:second}

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
       item & item \\
       item & item \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\section{next section}
\begin{figure}
                      \begin{center}
                        %\includegraphics{Pictures/isolation}
                        \vspace{5in}
                        \caption{second figure}
                        \label{fig:second}
                      \end{center}
                    \end{figure}                    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The table of contents is formatted using `\chapter*` which adds a 40pt gap below the title (report class).  You can edit it using etoolbox.  This will also affect `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables` and possibly others.

There is also a blank line added before each chapter in the TOC, LOF and LOT.  This is done via `\addtocontents` in `\chapter`.

```
\documentclass[14.5pt]{report}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\bullet$}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize CONTENTS \hfill}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\normalsize \hspace{2.4in} LIST OF FIGURES}

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\normalsize  \hspace{2.4in}  LIST OF TABLES}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{chngpage}

\usepackage[labelsep=period,figurename = FIG.]{caption}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\marginsize{1.0in}{1.0in}{1.0in}{1.0in}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vskip 40\p@}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancyhf{}

\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage

BODY HERE
\chapter{first}
\begin{table}
  \caption{first table}
  \label{tab:first}

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
       item & item \\
       item & item \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\section{first section}
\begin{figure}
                      \begin{center}
                        %\includegraphics[width=5in]{Pictures/needsimprovement}
                        \vspace{5in}
                        \caption{first figure}
                        \label{fig:first}
                      \end{center}
                    \end{figure}        
\chapter{second}
\begin{table}
  \caption{second table}
  \label{tab:second}

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
       item & item \\
       item & item \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\section{next section}
\begin{figure}
                      \begin{center}
                        %\includegraphics{Pictures/isolation}
                        \vspace{5in}
                        \caption{second figure}
                        \label{fig:second}
                      \end{center}
                    \end{figure}                    

\end{document}
```